# browser-sync watch not working

Tags: javascript, browser-sync

So I have a very simple setup, basically straight from browser-syncs [docs](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/api/#api-watch) however no matter what I do, I cannot get it to trigger a change event on watched files. Frustrating.

Here is my code:

```
var sync = require('browser-sync').create();
sync.watch([
    "react/**/*.{js,css,scss,html}",
    "static/**/**", "factories/factories.js"
]).on('change', sync.reload);

sync.init({
    proxy: 'localhost:8000',
    port: 4200,
    ghostMode: false,
    reloadOnRestart: true,
    open: false,
    notify: false,
    minify: false,
    logLevel: "silent"
});
```

I have another system watching those files just to test, and when I make a change to one - browser-sync does nothing while my other watcher reports a file change. Help?

Comment: I suggest making sure that your paths to the watch files are correct (maybe you need `./react, ./static`, etc.) and also making sure that you are running at least version 2.6.0 (per the docs)

Comment: Both suggestions are met. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems BS's watch doesn't read relative paths like `react` or `./react`. Changing the path to `__dirname + '/react/**/*.{js,css,scss,html}'` worked.